How to export a Datastore Kind to Google Cloud Storage that is from a different database than (default)?
In this documentation provided by google cloud I cannot find any property to set for datastoreId.
I am using the code from one of the answers that was given to this question, to export kinds that are set in the (default) database in Datastore. No ideea tho how to set it so that I can export kinds from a different database.
package com.google.example.datastore;

import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityService;
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFactory;
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

@WebServlet(name = "CloudDatastoreExport", value = "/cloud-datastore-export")
public class CloudDatastoreExport extends HttpServlet {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CloudDatastoreExport.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    // Verify outputURL parameter
    String outputUrlPrefix = request.getParameter("output_url_prefix");

    if (outputUrlPrefix == null || !outputUrlPrefix.matches("^gs://.*")) {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      response.getWriter().println("Error: Must provide a valid output_url_prefix.");

    } else {

      // Get project ID
      String projectId = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId();
      // Remove partition information to get plain app ID
      String appId = projectId.replaceFirst("(.*~)", "");

      // Get access token
      ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
      scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore");
      final AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
      final AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken =
          appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);

      // Read export parameters
      // If output prefix does not end with slash, add a timestamp
      if (!outputUrlPrefix.substring(outputUrlPrefix.length() - 1).contentEquals("/")) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        outputUrlPrefix = outputUrlPrefix + "/" + timeStamp + "/";
      }

      String[] namespaces = request.getParameterValues("namespace_id");
      String[] kinds = request.getParameterValues("kind");

      // Build export request
      JSONObject exportRequest = new JSONObject();
      exportRequest.put("output_url_prefix", outputUrlPrefix);

      JSONObject entityFilter = new JSONObject();

      if (kinds != null) {
        JSONArray kindsJSON = new JSONArray(kinds);
        entityFilter.put("kinds", kinds);
      }

      if (namespaces != null) {
        JSONArray namespacesJSON = new JSONArray(namespaces);
        entityFilter.put("namespaceIds", namespacesJSON);
      }

      exportRequest.put("entityFilter", entityFilter);

      URL url = new URL("https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + appId + ":export");
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());

      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
      exportRequest.write(writer);
      writer.close();

      if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        JSONTokener exportResponseTokens = new JSONTokener(connection.getInputStream());
        JSONObject exportResponse = new JSONObject(exportResponseTokens);

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().println("Export started:\n" + exportResponse.toString(4));

      } else {
        InputStream s = connection.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String errorMessage =
            String.format(
                "got error (%d) response %s from %s",
                connection.getResponseCode(), CharStreams.toString(r), connection.toString());
        log.warning(errorMessage);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().println("Failed to initiate export.");
      }
    }
  }
}

I was expecting to have a place in the request body or request parametrs where I could specify the datastoreId.

You mentioned Google Cloud Storage in the title of this post, and you tagged it google-cloud-storage, but I don't see how that product is involved at all here.  Please edit it out if it's not relevant to the task at hand.

Don't know how it how works for Java specifically but maybe the principle for other languages can help you figure it out. In NodeJs or Python, databaseId is an optional parameter you include when initializing a datastore connection. After doing this, all subsequent operations against the datastore is run against that database. If the option isn't specified, your operations are run against the default database.

To export from a named Firestore in Datastore mode database, use the Firestore export RPC (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import).  A kind will map directly to a collection-id.
